# Jasmine error- Expected event [object Object] to have been triggered on .div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I am using Jasmine and Jasmine-JQuery

My Jasmine code:

```
it("comp move resulted in an X", function() {
    var spyEvent = spyOnEvent('.div', 'click');
    $('.div').click();
    expect('click').toHaveBeenTriggeredOn('.div');
    expect(spyEvent).toHaveBeenTriggered();
});
```

my Jasmine output:

**Expected event [object Object] to have been triggered on .div**

-and-

**Expected event click to have been triggered on .div**

I copied this almost verbatim from the [Jasmine-JQuery guide](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery).

I can't seem to figure out why my test is failing despite having almost identical code from the docs. If anyone has any similar issues, check out this similar question: [Error on Jasmine - Expected event click to have been triggered on #DIV_ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23486444/error-on-jasmine-expected-event-click-to-have-been-triggered-on-div-id). I doesn't answer mine but it might answer yours.

I'm not sure if this helps give context as to why this is going on but within my spec-runner.js file and my app.js file, both have this piece of code:

```
console.log($('.div').text());
```

my HTML:

```
<div id="1" class="div">X</div>
```

within spec-runner.js, the console prints ''

and within app.js, the console prints 'X'

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems then that you have not loaded your HTML fixtures properly

This test below passes in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nicholas_Murray/h72onhrw/) and replicates your error if the load fixtures is commented out.

```
beforeEach(function() {
    setFixtures('<div id="1" class="div">X</div>');
});


it("comp move resulted in an X", function() {
    var spyEvent = spyOnEvent('.div', 'click');
    $('.div').click();
    expect('click').toHaveBeenTriggeredOn('.div');
    expect(spyEvent).toHaveBeenTriggered();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That error was not in my actual code, I was changing the code for this question to '.div' from my specific class I had in my actual code. I edited this question to account for that typo.

Comment: But your comment brings up a good point. It must be something bigger than my code.

Comment: I'm going to ask some people from work tomorrow why this would be happening because I think it has to do with my jQuery versions and file structure. When I do though, I'll come back and track to explain it for future users. Thanks for helping Nicholas!

Comment: I think it is to do with how you are loading your html fixtures